# How to add an object to an object?

Tags: .net, vb.net, soap, multidimensional-array

I make the same SOAP call to the same service running on 5 servers. All of the `TWeeksHeld` collections being returned need to be concatenated together into an *output* version of the same object (`TDAEHeldList`).  Here are my classes:

```
Partial Public Class TDAEHeldList      
    Private siteIdField As String        
    Private countField As Integer        
    Private returnCodeField As String        
    Private errorMessageField As String        
    Private daeWeeksHeldField() As TWeeksHeld
End Class

Partial Public Class TWeeksHeld        
    Private checkInField As String        
    Private resortNameField As String        
    Private countryField As String        
    Private regionField As String        
    Private localityField As String        
    Private weekIdField As String        
    Private bedroomsField As String        
    Private sleepsField As String        
    Private bookingTypeField As String        
    Private resortIdField As String        
    Private timeToExpiryField As String        
    Private specialFlagField As String        
    Private extMemberNoField As String        
    Private stockDisplayField As String        
    Private ownerBusCatCodeField As String
End Class
```

Each call needs to add the contents of the `daeWeeksHeldField()` collection to the output classes' `daeWeeksHeldField()` collection.

I have the following working:

```
Dim returnData As New TDAEHeldList
Dim weeksOnHold As New TDAEHeldList
Dim weeksOnHoldArray As TWeeksHeld
weeksOnHold = WSCaller.GetForeignWeeksOnHold(siteID,affiliateMemberID)
```

Then try to add the

```
weeksOnHoldArray += String.Concat(weeksOnHoldArray, weeksOnHold.daeWeeksHeldField)
```

Followed by:

```
returnData.daeWeeksHeldField = weeksOnHoldArray.ToArray(GetType(TWeeksHeld))
```

I've also tried:

```
for Each x As Object In weeksOnHold.daeWeeksHeld
  weeksOnHoldArray.Add(x)
Next
```

plus a couple of other Googled techniques.  Is what I want to do possible or not and if so, how is it done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You refer to the `daeWeeksHeldField` property as a *collection*, but it is not a collection.  It is an array.  Arrays certainly have their uses, but in this case, what you really want is a collection.  Collections allow you to add new items easily.  Arrays on, the other hand, cannot dynamically grow automatically, so they become cumbersome to use if the size of the list is not fixed.

The most common collection that is used, and the one I would recommend, is `List(Of T)`.  Here is how you would use it:

```
Dim combinedWeeksOnHold As New List(Of TWeeksHeld)
Dim weeksOnHold1 = WSCaller1.GetForeignWeeksOnHold(siteID1, affiliateMemberID1)
If weeksOnHold1.daeWeeksHeldField IsNot Nothing Then
    combinedWeeksOnHold.AddRange(weeksOnHold1.daeWeeksHeldField)
End If
Dim weeksOnHold2 = WSCaller2.GetForeignWeeksOnHold(siteID2, affiliateMemberID2)
If weeksOnHold2.daeWeeksHeldField IsNot Nothing Then
    combinedWeeksOnHold.AddRange(weeksOnHold2.daeWeeksHeldField)
End If
```

If you really need an array of them, at any point, you can call `List(Of T).ToArray`, like this:

```
Dim array() As TWeeksHeld = combinedWeeksOnHold.ToArray()
```

Comment: Thanks. A nice technique. However, some of the fields in daeWeeksHeldField are null (nothing) so it throws an exception.

Comment: The `AddRange` method wouldn't throw an exception if any of the properties of the items in the array were null.  You'll need to be more specific.  What did you try, which line threw the exception, and what kind of exception was it?

Comment: The line causing the exception was: combinedWeeksOnHold.AddRange(weeksOnHold.daeWeeksHeldField) 
And the exception was a System.ArgumentNulException of value "Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: collection"

Comment: I thought I'd already stated what the exception was in my previous comment. But if you mean the stack trace, it's:
Expression:DirectCast(ex,System.ArgumentNullException).StackTrace

Value:   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.InsertRange(Int32 index, IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at Site.daeoverbrandv2point7.WSGetWeeksOnHold(String authId, String externalMemberNo) in C:\VS2008_Solutions\DAEEur2\Site\websvcs\daeoverbrandv2_7.asmx.vb:line 1331
Sorry if I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  It was what I had suspected all along, but I wanted to be sure.  I updated my answer to fix that.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in marking the answer. My web service fell over. It's all working nicely now though so thanks for your help :)